# Index Sources & Publish Symbols step not publish symbols in TFS 2015

Tags: indexing, tfsbuild, symbols, tfs-2015

I have a problem with publishing symbols (move to shared directory on symbol server) using Index Sources & Publish Symbols step in TFS 2015 build definition.

I have simple Hello World project - one dll, one pdb in output and simple TFS 2015 build definition. Build definition contains two steps.

1. VS Build - Build solution \**\*.sln (with default configuration)
2. Index Sources and Publish Symbols - Publish symbols path: \\sw\\symbols (with default configuration and shared directory symbols on sw pc). This location works ok with XAML Build Definitions!

**When i queue new build, everything seems ok (variables have right content and so on) but shared folder on symbol server not contains desired pdb file.**

Please check following (truncation) TFS 2015 build log. Thanks.

```
Starting: Build  
Starting: Get sources  
Checked out branch refs/heads/master for repository 1400666 at commit bd3b859e312be62d8af976f233f7407863ba33b8
Running tasks  

Starting task: Build solution \**\*.sln  
Build succeeded.  
    0 Warning(s)
    0 Error(s)
Time Elapsed 00:00:00.60  
Finishing task: VSBuild  

Starting task: Publish symbols path: \\sw\\symbols  
Executing the powershell script: C:\BuildAgent\tasks\PublishSymbols\1.0.4\PublishSymbols.ps1  
Find-Files -SearchPattern **\bin\**\*.pdb -RootFolder C:\BuildAgent\_work\57cae171\1400666  
>pdbFile= C:\BuildAgent\_work\57cae171\1400666\HelloWorld\bin\Debug\HelloWorld.pdb  
>Found 1 files to index...  
Invoke-IndexSources -RepositoryEndpoint repositoryEndpoint -SourceFolder C:\BuildAgent\_work\57cae171\1400666 -PdbFiles pdbFiles  
>Invoke-PublishSymbols -PdbFiles pdbFiles -Share \\sw02\\symbols -Product Build -Version 20160108.7 -MaximumWaitTime 7200000 -MaximumSemaphoreAge 1440 -ArtifactName Symbols_debug  
Start: AssociateArtifact  
Associated artifact 15 with build 986  
End: AssociateArtifact  
Finishing task: PublishSymbols  

Worker Worker-e99a050a-0cc5-477e-bf6f-cd374173434f finished running job e99a050a-0cc5-477e-bf6f-cd374173434f  
Finishing Build
```

**NOTE:** publish symbols using symstore.exe (in my ps1 script in powershell build step) works.

Comment: According to the logs, the symbols file has been published to \\sw02\symbols folder. When the vNext build publish the symbols to a folder, it will create a folder like "000Admin" in it and record the add file information in the folder. Can you check if it is there?

Comment: No, is not. The symbol folder is still empty.

Comment: Are you able to solve this. For me this task is working fine but when I debug like consumer it is showing D\1\a... location and saying file is not found on local system. After this task how you debug. I used this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/artifacts/symbols/debug-with-symbols-visual-studio?view=azure-devops

Comment: You have to put into your question, that most *obvious* things has been tried and checked. I'm surprised no-one suggested reinstall.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the same issue when the path to publish symbols (your shared dir) has a "\" at the end.  I had a path set to something like \bldmachine\final\symbols\ and everything appeared to succeed, but there were no symbols published.  Only when I deleted the trailing "\" did it start working.  Final working path was like \bldmachine\final\symbols

Comment: This probably is not my case. I use path like \\sw02\symbols and publish still not working. Btw may not path to the shared folder start with double slash? In your case \\bldmachine\final\symbols?

Answer (score 0):

I just reproduce this issue after I enter a redundant blank space at the end of the path. So you may need to check the publish symbols path in your build definition, make sure there is no redundant space in it.

Comment: No, I don't any redundant spaces in symbol path.

Comment: @honza Then does the "symbols" folder exist on \\sw02? As I observed, the task can only publish the files to an exist path, it cannot create folder.

Comment: Yes, the "symbols" folder exists! I can connect co sw02 machine (through mstsc for example) and explore "symbols" folder. As well I can show \\sw02\symbols on browser.

Comment: @honza Did you made some changes in the error log? It is \\sw here: "Publish symbols path: \\sw\\symbols", but \\sw02 "-Share \\sw02\\symbols -Product Build"  here.

Comment: I'm very sorry! I have two share folders \\sw\symbols and \\sw02\symbols (sw02 is build machine). I have same problem with both locations!

Comment: Redundant spaces? Check the path? Why isn't anyone suggesting reboot and reinstall windows, while we at completely random suggestions? You lot...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and the problem was related with how PDB was generated. It can be modified in project settings.

As mention in [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/index-sources-publish-symbols?view=azure-devops) portable PDB are not compatible and the file is ignored during process, you can check it setting system.debug = True.

To fix it you need to update your Debug project settings.

Over VisualStudio go to "Project -> [ProjectName] Properties... -> Build"

Here you can select for which Configuration. If not sure you can select "All configurations" then click on "Advanced..." and change "**Debugging information**" to **Full**

It is also possible to update the project manually with the following

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|AnyCPU'">
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|AnyCPU'">
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
  </PropertyGroup>
```